# PowerBI - Split Table (Normalization)

Tags: split, powerbi, database-normalization

I want to split following table in Power BI using DAX expressions:

[Click here to see ***SCREENSHOT*** of Tables Schema - Before & After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db7gm.png)

i am able to create two tables "Customer" and "Car" using "GroupBy" DAX function, but couldn't create the bridge-table "CustomerCar".

**those ID numbers are just for reference. After inserting the User and Car records, we need to use their IDs (Auto-increment IDs)  ... any idea ?**

Please help

Comment: Can one customer purchase multiple cars? If Yes, then I don't think you will be able to create a correct "Customer Car" table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works for you. I didn't use using groupby. Creating three separate tables using data sample you provided.

**For Customer table**

```
Customer = SELECTCOLUMNS('Source Table',"ID",'Source Table'[id]+100,"First Name",'Source Table'[first_name],"Last Name",'Source Table'[last_name])
```

**For Car table**

```
Car = SELECTCOLUMNS('Source Table',"ID",'Source Table'[id]+10000,"Car_Make",'Source Table'[Car_make],"Car_model",'Source Table'[car_model],"Car_Year",'Source Table'[car_vear],"Car_Price",'Source Table'[car_price])
```

**Customer Car table**

```
CustomerCar = SELECTCOLUMNS('Source Table',"ID",'Source Table'[id], "Customer_ID",'Source Table'[id]+100, "Car_id",'Source Table'[id]+10000)
```

Comment: those ID numbers are just for reference.  After inserting the User and Car records, we need to use their IDs (Auto-increment IDs) .... in your example we are explicitly creating those IDs by adding 100 & 1000 .... instead we should be getting the auto-inserted IDs (with out doing +100 or +1000) ... any idea ?